# export const with async await TypeError: callback is not a function

Tags: node.js, async-await

I'm having the error:

> TypeError: callback is not a function

However I could not find out the reason, any help will be appreciated.

```
export const addTaskToQueue = async asyncQueue => {
    if (shouldStop()) {
        return
    }
    const proxy = getProxy()
    if (proxy === null) {
        return
    }
    const context = await getNextContext()
    logger.debug('', `Adding task to queue for ${getId(context, proxy)}`)
    asyncQueue.push({ context, proxy }, async error => {
        if (error) {
            logger.error('', error)
        }
        logger.debug('', `${getId(context, proxy)} finished`)
        await addTaskToQueue(asyncQueue)
    })
}
```

Where this function is called:

```
    const asyncQueue = queue(async (task, callback) => {
        const { context, proxy } = task
        logger.debug('', `Running ${getId(context, proxy)}`)
        await runWorkflow(context, proxy)
        return callback()
    }, configuration.concurrency)
    for (let task = 0; task < configuration.initialTaskCount; task += 1) {
        await addTaskToQueue(asyncQueue)
    }
}
```

It appears that the stack trace for the error is actually in line

> return callback()

Comment: Which line of code is that TypeError associated with?  What is the entire message and stack trace?  Since there's no variable named `callback` in this code, it appears the error comes from some other code.

Comment: @jfriend00, the error is printed in the logger.error() line, and that is the whole message. The message does not include a stack trace. That function is called in another class after a queue being created and passed as an argument to the function. What I'm struggling with is that in order to run the asyncQueue.push() line, "asyncQueue" has to be a queue object, that's why I am passing a queue as the argument while calling the function in another class, but since i'm getting that error, i'm not able to pass a queue as the argument, it asks for a function.

Comment: What is `asyncQueue`?  Does it come from a specific module on NPM you're using?  If so, please include a link to that module.  If not, please include the code for that object as it seems possible, you're not using that correctly so we need to see the code/doc for that.

Comment: Also, in your `if (error) { }` block, you should probably `return` or use an `else` so you don't execute `await addTaskToQueue(asyncQueue)` is there was an error.

Comment: The code you have provided is not enough to trigger such an error. Can you provide code that actually *calls* `addTaskToQueue` and which then results in that error? What was the output you got *before* the error occurred? Did it include any `Adding task to queue for...` messages, any `... finished` messages?

Comment: Any reaction to other comments I made? Also, the code you added just increases the number of dependencies that are not detailed. What are all those other functions that are called? Can you minimise the code needed to reproduce the issue, but with all dependencies available, so we can actually reproduce the issue? You point out the error occurs at `callback()`, but in all the code you have provided you have not added the code that actually defines `callback`. Obviously it is not a function... when it should have been.

Comment: @trincot, I added function callback(){} before calling the callback function and it seems to resolve the problem. Thanks to you and jfriend00 who helped.